# Ruby !sub returning strange null

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the result of the first line. It's supposed to return a file name without extension if the file has one. Can somebody explain to me why it is like that and also tell me what would be a more proper here?

```
irb(main):003:0> 'fafeafeafewafeawfeaw'.sub!(/\.[^\.]*$/, '')
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> '.fafeafeafewafeawfeaw'.sub!(/\.[^\.]*$/, '')
=> ""
irb(main):005:0> 'fafeafeafewafea.wfeaw'.sub!(/\.[^\.]*$/, '')
=> "fafeafeafewafea"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is documented that the sub! (like many of the ! string operations) return nil if no change was made.

From the [docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub%21)

> > Performs the substitutions of String#sub in place, returning str, or **nil** if no substitutions were performed.

Instead use the regular sub. In your case the extra bang (!) is unnecessary.

`'fafeafeafewafeawfeaw'.sub(/\.[^\.]*$/, '')`

## Bang Methods

The difference between `sub` and `sub!` is subtle. But in ruby in general, the non bang (!) version of a method is safer. Since by convention the bang means the method has more side affects.

In the case of string functions (and many array/enumerable functions) the bang means the method operates on the contents of the caller, instead of making (and returning) a copy.

```
s = 'fafafa'
puts s #=> 'fafafa'

puts s.sub(/fa/, 'fo') #=> 'fofofo'

puts s #=> 'fafafa'

puts s.sub!(/fa/, 'fo') #=> 'fofofo'

puts s #=> 'fofofo'
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It's a bit confusing that methods with '!' behave in a different way.

Comment: Confusing indeed, but that is what the `!` is for! It is a library author warning you 'Hey this method has strange(er) behaviour'. In general there won't be a `!` method (bang method) without a non bang version. (Or at least that's the idea)